# unable to import QForm

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm new to Quasar but am none-the-less trying to use the [QForm component](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/form). When I modify `resources/quasar/quasar.conf.js` to include `QForm`, however, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown import from Quasar: QForm
```

Here's how the framework / components bit looks after I added QForm:

```
framework: {
  components: [
    'QLayout',
    'QLayoutHeader',
    'QLayoutDrawer',
    'QPageContainer',
    'QPage',
    'QToolbar',
    'QToolbarTitle',
    'QBtn',
    'QIcon',
    'QList',
    'QListHeader',
    'QItem',
    'QItemMain',
    'QItemSide',
    'QField',
    'QInput',
    'QSpinnerMat',
    'QCard',
    'QTooltip',
    'QForm'
  ],
```

Here's my `quasar dev` output:

```
 Dev mode.......... spa
 Quasar theme...... mat
 Quasar CLI........ v0.17.25
 Quasar Framework.. v0.17.20
 Debugging......... enabled
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently QForm was added in Version 1.0. I need to upgrade to use it:

https://quasar.dev/start/upgrade-guide#Upgrading-from-older-v1-to-latest-v1